# How to change state in Dropdown semantic-ui-react

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to change state onChange in Dropdown Component

```
const DropdownDomainSelection = () => (
      <Dropdown placeholder='Select Friend' selection options={domainsList} onChange={this.handleDomainsSelectChange} />
    )



handleDomainsSelectChange = (e, data) => {
    this.setState({
      currantDomain_id: data.value,
      currantWidget_id: "null",
    }, () => {
      console.log('this.state.currantDomain_id',this.state.currantDomain_id);
    });
  }
```

The state changes fine.
Problem is that Dropdown's value always returns to default 'Select Friend'.

How can I make Dropdown change it's state to selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropdown component is missing a value prop.  The value prop controls the current value of Dropdown.  Just add the prop `value = {this.state.currantDomain_id}` to it.

Comment: Also, make sure your option prop contains an array of objects in which each object contains a value key. e.g. `[{key:'', text:'', value:''}, {key:'', text:'', value:''},]`